# error: cannot find symbol method getDownloadUrl() having this error

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

I am creating an android classifieds app and stuck on this for 2 days, i cannot understand what to do as i am new to firebase and android. I am trying to upload image from the camera or from the storage on the firebase. Here is my code

```
private void executeUploadTask() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "uploading image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    final String postId = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().getKey();

    final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("posts/users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() +
                    "/" + postId + "/post_image");

    UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putBytes(mUploadBytes);
    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Post Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //insert the download url into the firebase database
            Uri firebaseUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: firebase download url: " + firebaseUri.toString());
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

            Post post = new Post();
            post.setImage(firebaseUri.toString());
            post.setCity(mCity.getText().toString());
            post.setContact_email(mContactEmail.getText().toString());
            post.setCountry(mContactEmail.getText().toString());
            post.setDescription(mDescription.getText().toString());
            post.setPost_id(postId);
            post.setPrice(mPrice.getText().toString());
            post.setState_province(mStateProvince.getText().toString());
            post.setTitle(mTitle.getText().toString());
            post.setUser_id(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

            reference.child(getString(R.string.node_posts))
                    .child(postId)
                    .setValue(post);

            resetFields();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "could not upload photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            double currentProgress = (100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
            if( currentProgress > (mProgress + 15)){
                mProgress = (100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                Log.d(TAG, "onProgress: upload is " + mProgress + "& done");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mProgress + "%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: have you checked to see you have no typo's in that methodname?

Answer (score 0):

UploadTask.getDownloadUrl() is deprecated. Use StorageReference.getDownloadUrl() instead.